# UIImageView centering issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

To understand my problem let's follow this steps.

1. Open - XCode -> New Project -> View based application.
2. Open View Controller.xib file.
3. Drag an image-view into viewController's view.
4. Place that image view on center of viewController's view.
5. Apply size of 125x125 to image-view.
6. Take any image with dimension of 320 width & 460 height.
7. Drag that image into your application resources directory.
8. Now, Again back to .xib File & select image-view
9. Set image (which is in your resources) to image-view
10. Set Image-view Mode to - Center

Ok. Let me explain the situation now.

- after performing all above steps - image-view has an image which is larger than image-view's size.
- However, Image-view places that image on center & in View controller image-view is looking proper ( not scaled ).
- But When you run your application, image-view will be displayed in size of 320x460. ( but it is not actually scaled. )

Now, I can't find the reason, why interface builder is displaying something else & simulator/iphone is displaying something else ?

My Query.

- I want the image's center portion within image-view no matter what image size is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the IB click on your image and in drawing section Check "**Clip subviews**" Option